# Why is the component map option for react-i18next not the preferred format for doing complex translations?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

This question pertains to the `<Trans>` component from `react-i18next`.

Browsing around react-i18next, and having used it for years, I've been so used to using the index based node format. I will admit, it took some time to wrap my head around.

I came across an alternative format that is honestly not super well documented or maybe I should say, not really called out in the documentation as the preferred way of utilizing the `<Trans>` component using the `components` prop and a mapping of symbol name to `React.ReactNode`.

I feel like this format is way more intuitive, so I would like to learn a bit more why has this not been brought to the forefront in the documentation? Is it more of a newer format and as a result to keep everyone happy, leave the original approach as the documented one?

Since comparing things like:

```
"HELLO_WORLD": <0>The cow<1>well this cow is inside</1>and now im back out <3>just for fun></3>end</0>

and used like

<Trans i18nKey="HELLO_WORLD">
  <h1>
    The cow (but honestly it doesnt matter what i put here since it gets replaced)
    <h2>well this is inside</h2>
    now we out
    <h3>funzies</h3>
  </h1>
</Trans>
```

to anyone who hasnt used the `Trans` component this is like a "wtf, this must be a typo. Why did we skip from node 1 to 3? Where did 2 go?". And dont get me started on nesting where the node indices reset.

Comparing that to:

```
"HELLO_WORLD": <WRAPPER>The cow<INNER>well this cow is inside</INNER>and now im back out <SIBLING>just for fun></SIBLING>end</WRAPPER>

and used like (just an example btw)

const Wrapper = (props) => <h1>{props.children}</h1>;
const Inner = (props) => <h2>{props.children}</h2>;
const Sibling = (props) => <h3>{props.children}</h3>;

<Trans
 i18nKey="HELLO_WORLD"
 components={{
   WRAPPER: <Wrapper />,
   INNER: <Inner />,
   SIBLING: <Sibling />
 }}
/>
```

Just curious if theres some edge cases or things I'm not aware of where one is more advantageous over the other.

Comment: it is documented here, isn’t it? https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-which-lists-the-components-v11.6.0

Comment: Yea I guess I was asking more since I was curious why that isn't the go to example. Or perhaps its more just a documentation thing. The docs don't seem to really push for this method, though it seems a lot easier to wrap ones head around. At least to me that is